# ConnectivityManager only can detect connectivity but not network availability

Tags: android, kotlin

The code below is used to detect network connectivity. The scenario is the software connected to the phone's hotspot but the phone's cellular network doesn't switch on. The code below return isConnected = true, which means it is only detects connectivity? The question is how I change it to detect network availability?

```
fun Context.isOnline(): Boolean {
val connectivityManager =
    this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo

if (networkInfo == null) {
    log(message = "Network info is **NULL**")
    return false
} else {
    val isConnected = when(networkInfo.detailedState) {
        NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTING -> true
        NetworkInfo.DetailedState.AUTHENTICATING -> true
        NetworkInfo.DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR -> true
        NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED -> true
        NetworkInfo.DetailedState.VERIFYING_POOR_LINK -> true
        else -> false
    }

    if (!isConnected) {
        log(message = "Network state is **${networkInfo.detailedState?.name ?: "NULL"}**")
    }

    return isConnected
}
```

}

Comment: The most basic thing to check network availability would be using something like `ping`, other than that you're right this only detects connectivity not availability.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a deprecated API with `NetworkInfo`. You should be using [NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.html#NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)

> Indicates that connectivity on this network was successfully validated. For example, for a network with NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET, it means that Internet connectivity was successfully detected.

**SDK >= 23**

You could change your code to something like this to see if that's `true` to confirm internet connectivity:

```
connectivityManager
.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork())
.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)
```

**SDK >= 21**

If you are using anything as old as SDK 21, you can use the [`ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)) API.

```
boolean isConnected = false;

final NetworkRequest request =
  new NetworkRequest.Builder()
  .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)
  .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
  .build();

final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

final NetworkCallback networkCallback = new NetworkCallback() {
  @Override
  void onAvailable(Network network) {
      // Triggers when this network is available.
      isConnected = true;
  }

  @Override
  void onLost(Network network) {
      // Triggers when this network is lost.
      isConnected = false;
  }
};

connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback);
```

Comment: The 'connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()' only available for sdk 23 and above but my android sdk is only 22. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Updated to support as low as sdk 21.